# How to remove values from json array?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a json file consisting of a single array. the array consists of objects with the keys name, title, pay, age. How can I delete an entire object by the value of the Name key? I am using the "simple json" library, it is quite old, but it suits my purposes. Sorry, there is a lot of code, I don't know what to show. Thank.

```
  public class Json {

   static JSONArray jsonArray;
   public static void JsonWriter(String filePath, String fullname, String age, String pay, String post) {
      try {
         JSONObject worker = new JSONObject();
         worker.put("name", fullname);
         worker.put("age", new Integer(age));
         worker.put("post", post);
         worker.put("pay",  new Integer(pay));

         jsonArray.add(worker);

         FileWriter file = new FileWriter(filePath);
         file.write(jsonArray.toString());
         file.flush();
         file.close();

      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   //add object
   public static void AddWorker() throws IOException, ParseException {
      System.out.println("input name");
      String name = handleInput();
      System.out.println("input post");
      String post = handleInput();
      System.out.println("input age");
      String age = handleInput();
      System.out.println("input pay");
      String pay = handleInput();
      System.out.println("succes");
      JsonWriter("res\\Worker List.json", name, age, pay, post);
      WorkerList();
   }
   public static void DeleteWorker()
   {
      System.out.println(ansi().fg(RED).a("Input name").reset());
      String name = handleInput();

   }

   //add object
   public static void WorkerList() throws IOException, ParseException {
      Iterator i = jsonArray.iterator();
      while (i.hasNext())
      {
         System.out.println(Menu.Separator);
         JSONObject innearObj = (JSONObject) i.next();
         System.out.println("name: " + innearObj.get("name") + lineSeparator() +
                 "age: " + innearObj.get("age") + lineSeparator() +
                 "post: " + innearObj.get("post") + lineSeparator() +
                 "pay: " + innearObj.get("pay"));
      }
      System.out.println(Menu.Separator);
      System.out.println("Add new object?" + lineSeparator() + "0 - Yes" + lineSeparator() + "1 - No");
      switch(handleInput())
      {
         case ("0"):
            AddWorker();
            break;
      }
   }

   //Parsing json file
   public static void WorkersParser(String filePath)
   {
      try {
         JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
         Object obj = jsonParser.parse(new FileReader(filePath));
         jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;
         WorkerList();
      } catch (IOException | ParseException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}

 public static String handleInput() {
    try {
        String input;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        input = reader.readLine();
        return input;
    }
    catch (Exception ignored) { }
    return "";
}
```

////

```
   [
  {
    "post":"post1",
    "name":"name1",
    "pay":1,
    "age":1
  },
  {
    "post":"post2", 
    "name":"name2", //if name = "post2", delete // {
    "pay":2,                                    //    "post":"post2",
    "age":2                                     //    "name":"name2",
  }                                             //    "pay":"2",
]                                               //    "age":2
                                                // }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to get some good quality answers I would recommend taking the time to show us the code you used to attempt the problem, what results you had and what further research you have done. I would recommend taking a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips!

Comment: your question does not clear where from you want to delete the object? File, console etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop all of them, check for that parameter and [remove()](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/net/sf/json/JSONArray.html#remove(int)) by the index:

```
String jsonString =  "[{\"post\":\"post1\",\"name\":\"name1\",\"pay\":1,\"age\":1},{\"post\":\"post2\",\"name\":\"name2\",\"pay\":2,\"age\":2}]";
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(jsonString);
String wordToDeleteBy = "name1";
System.out.println(arr.length()); //prints 2
for (int i = 0; i<arr.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
    if (obj.has("name") && obj.get("name").equals(wordToDeleteBy)) {
        arr.remove(i);
    }
}
System.out.println(arr.length()); //prints 1
```

Comment: Are you using some other library? JSONArray cannot accept String in constructor. Also, JSONArray does not have a .lenght method and a .getJSONObject method. And JSONObject doesn't have a .has method. I tried using your method, but I get an IndexOutOfBoundsException error.

https://pastebin.com/Ne2jpqNw

Comment: Oh, I didn't catch that you are using a different one. I am using standard [org.json library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20201115) from

Comment: I find this one (not the org.json.simple) always compatible with my problems and solves them well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this library is not very different from Simple Json. I'll try to rewrite my code for it.

Comment: Shouldn't be much to change as the base is kinda the same. Feel free to accept this answer if it helps :)